# jsPDF multipage pdf - text overlapping

Tags: javascript, jspdf

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<script>
var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'pt',
    format: 'a4'
});

doc.html(document.querySelector('#my-div'), {
    callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('file.pdf');
    },
    margin: [30, 30, 30, 30],
    x: 32,
    y: 32,
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.6,
        width: 1000
    },
    autoPaging: 'text',  // This line is needed to ensure smooth text flow across pages but it causes text overlapping vertically.

});
</script>
```

There is a line in above code that cause text overlapping.
How to solve this text overlapping problem?

Comment: What if you `autoPaging` set it to 'none' or simply remove it from your code?

Comment: this code works for me; how ever you missed a comma at the. end of margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc.html(document.querySelector('#my-div'), {
    callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('file.pdf');
    },
    margin: [41, 41, 41, 41],
    x: 33,
    y: 33,
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.6,
        width: 1000
    },
    autoPaging: 'text',  // This line is needed to ensure smooth text flow across pages but it causes text overlapping vertically.

});
```

This code shows content of my-div properly in generated pdf file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).